# how to set default value in select option when I have only two option?

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu, tags, html-select

here my code

```
<select class="form-control" 
   aria-placeholder="select auth type" id="auth_type" 
   [(ngModel)]="authenticationType" 
   name="auth_type"
   #auth_type="ngModel" 
   (change)="changeAuthenticationType($event)" required>
                    <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled  selected>{{'AUTHENTICATION_CONFIGURATION.SELECT_TYPE' | translate}}
                    </option>
                    <option value="ALIGNOR_AUTHENTICATION">ALIGNOR AUTHENTICATION</option>
                    <option value="COGNITO_AUTHENTICATION">COGNITO AUTHENTICATION</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not done it by the recommended way of doing it.

Refer  [this demo code to see](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-default-option-value-qtq3kb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) how it done. I would recommend to do it this way.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
  <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">{{item.value}}</option>
</select>
```

You can make changes in your code accordingly.

Comment: I have  only two options not using array

Comment: @AnisaShaikh Create an array with values like `{ key: 'ALIGNOR_AUTHENTICATION', value: 'ALIGNOR AUTHENTICATION' },`  . I do not see a problem there . If not, then replace `value` with `[ngValue]` in your code

Comment: something is not working even if i take array,i think problem is in [(ngModel)]

Comment: Create a fork from my example and share the demo code for the same. Otherwise, I can't help more than that

Comment: how can i use value of api in another function?

Comment: @AnisaShaikh : Do you have the question posted ?